# increments without unsigned?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Im trying to create initial migrations for an existing project.

All the tables primary keys are defined as

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

But, when i use:

```
table.increments();
```

It executes:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

In Knex documentation there's only a chainable method `unsigned`... but not a `signed` one.

How can I remove the "unsigned" modifier?

Comment: why do you want it to be signed since you're autoincrementing it so it can't be less than the first value (which should be 0) ?

Comment: I don't know `knex` but having `unsigned int` as datatype means you have 2x size. And as pointed in previous comment, auto increment should be used as with positive int only.

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with both of you, but the system is already running as is. I need to develop new features, and i want to manage new database changes through knex migrations

Answer (score 1):

No other way to do it except by writing:

`.specificType('id', 'int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT')`

```
knex.schema.createTable('table', t => {
  t.specificType('id', 'int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT');
}).toSQL()
```

https://runkit.com/embed/bjjle6jvsjlb

Comment: How to define it also as a primary key? I tried `t.specificType('id', 'int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT').primary();` and `t.primary("id")` after the specificType call... didn't worked... it says "ER_WRONG_AUTO_KEY: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"